# Server 2008 can't remove restricted site

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet-explorer

On server 2008 in the internet options (from IE) we are not able to adjust the Restricted Sites or Trusted Sites (yes we are logged in as administrator).  What might disable this functionality? (and how do we get it back).

It's a standalone server which we are using for remote apps.

Comment: Please post the exact error message, if you are encountering one. Or does it simply fall back to the previous settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try running Internet Explorer as an administrator (right-click Internet Explorer, and then click Run as administrator).

Comment: Hadn't tried that specifically, but no it doesn't help.

Comment: @Alister Is Internet Explorer: Enhanced Security Configuration enabled for administrators? It may be necessary to disable IE ESC. You can do so using Server Manager.

Comment: IE ESC has already been disabled.

Comment: @Alister Is a Local Group Policy object being used to configure IE?